# Side-by-side comparison is misleading when programming language is specified for code block

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, diff

This suggested edit queue item:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32261149

Marks the entire code block as changed.

[image]

But only the programming language (`cpp`) and the final `}` have been changed:

[image]

I assume the `cpp` is the culprit, and not the `}`. Anyway, this is misleading, and makes it unnecessarily difficult to see whether the code actually been manipulated.

On the other hand, the programming language would otherwise not have a visible element which could be shown in the diff. However, the current situation is too obfuscating.

Comment: Yes, but from an editor's or a reviewer's point of view, that's nonsense. I have to look at the markdown everytime that happens to check what *really* happened.

Comment: It's doubly nonsensical, because even if the red and green overlay did not *cover* any potential syntax highlighting (making it harder to judge the merit of the change), there still isn't any visible syntax highlighting in the edit history or review queue to begin with.

Comment: Eh, who uses the rendered view to review changes on the suggested edits queue?

Comment: I do, @Braiam, for example - switching back-n-forth between views when needed. [double-beep's userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9154/restore-syntax-highlighting-on-review-and-revision-pages) fixes loading of highlighting for review queues.